# Visual Studio Test Explorer not detecting Boost Tests

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I'm trying to get into testing in c++ using VS2015 with Boost, following this guide on [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-boost-test-for-cpp).

I've installed the boost unit test adapter from [the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ETASGmbH.BoostUnitTestAdapter).

If my understanding is correct, I should now be able to see my boost test cases in the test case explorer within VS2015 but somehow I don't see any of them. Building the project runs just fine and depending on whether my test cases are valid or not, the program exits with 0 or 201.

My project has a single .cpp file with the following contents:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(my_boost_test)
{   
    BOOST_CHECK(0==0);
}    

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(my_boost_test2)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(0==1);
}
```

Comment: Note that the page says "Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5". That is the latest *preview* of the next VS release.

Comment: Ugh, yes. I guess that explains it all. Thanks. Do you have an advice on where to look for Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: The 2015 requires an extension from the marketplace, but with VS2017 15.5 it should be included in the installer. Still doesn't explain why the 2015 version doesn't work.

Comment: It's working now after I installed a different extension from the marketplace called "TestExceWindow for Boost.Test". The extension is designed as an additional window which works fine, but now tests are also properly registered in the builtin Test Explorer.

Comment: I just found that for me with VS2017, the marketplace solution _appearead_ to work but did not reliably so. It's last update was 2017.. VS2017 does support it out of the box (without the marketplace addon) _if_ you choose to install the Boost.Test test adapter as part of the VS installation which was not the default in my case. Using the VS installer to install the adapter solved the issue for me.